# using Jinja2 template to copy content in a file with Anisible

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I would `jinja2 template` to copy some contents in a file depending on the `distribution_major_version`. So i am using if statement to achieve the goal. I have this file `/mytemplates/foo.j2`
Could you please confirm if this is the best practice to write the conditional statement or not?

```
{% if ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "6" %}
    line1
    line2
    line3

{% elif ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "7" or ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "8"%}
    
    line1 
    line4
    line6

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the data into a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
    lines:
      '6': |
        line1
        line2
        line3
      '7': |

        line1
        line4
        line6
      '8': |

        line1
        line4
        line6
```

Then, the template is trivial

```yaml
shell> cat templates/lines.txt.j2
{{ lines[ansible_distribution_major_version] }}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    lines:
      '6': |
        line1
        line2
        line3
      '7': |

        line1
        line4
        line6
      '20': |

        line1
        line4
        line20
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_distribution_major_version
    - template:
        src: lines.txt.j2
        dest: lines.txt
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_distribution_major_version: '20'

TASK [template] ******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
shell> cat lines.txt 

line1
line4
line20
```

---

Notes

- You can use

```yaml
ansible_distribution_major_version
```

instead of

```yaml
ansible_facts['distribution_major_version']
```

- You don't need the [bracket notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables). You can reference the attribute in **dot notation**

```yaml
ansible_facts.distribution_major_version
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but i should use the `jinja2 template`. So my question is it right to write the conditional statement `{% if ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "6" %}` or not

Comment: @medisamm You can also achieve that without a condition by having multiple template files named after the version number `src: foo_{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.j2`

Comment: You don't need any conditions when you put the data into a dictionary. I added a complete example.

Comment: @Khaled: Of course, you can. But this does not answer this question. It's not efficient to create a template for each version.

Comment: @VladimirBotka in the documentation that you referenced says: "Bracket notation always works. Dot notation can cause problems because some keys collide with attributes and methods of python dictionaries."
IMHO it's better to use bracket notation.